# Can't update state from the child component to parent component in react native

Tags: react-native, setstate

I'm new in the development of react-native.

I Can't update the state from the child component to the parent component in react-native.

Here is my child component

passing value from child component like this

```
<TouchableOpacity value='popularity' onPress={() => this.props.sortby('popularity')}>
                  <Text style={styles.drawer_menu_text_item} >Sort by popularity</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

this shows me error  :  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation')

Here is my child component

```
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (

    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#d1e8fd', }}>
      <ScrollView
        style={{ marginLeft: 0, backgroundColor: '#fff', padding: 15 }}
      >
        <View
          style={{ padding: 15, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderColor: "gray", marginTop: 15 }}>
          <Image source={require('./src/image/filters.png')} style={styles.drawer_menu_icontext} />
          <Text style={styles.drawer_menu_text}>Filters</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginLeft: 15, marginTop: 20, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Text style={styles.drawer_menu_text}>Default sorting</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={{ marginLeft: 15, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>

          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity value='popularity' onPress={() => this.props.sortby('popularity')}>
              <Text style={styles.drawer_menu_text_item} >Sort by popularity</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity value='rating' onPress={() => this.props.sortby('rating')}>
              <Text style={styles.drawer_menu_text_item}>Sort by average rating</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity >
            <TouchableOpacity value='date' onPress={() => this.props.sortby('date')}>
              <Text style={styles.drawer_menu_text_item}>Sort by latest</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity value='price' onPress={() => this.props.sortby('price')}>
              <Text style={styles.drawer_menu_text_item}>Sort by price: low to high</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity value='price-desc' onPress={() => this.props.sortby('price-desc')}>
              <Text style={styles.drawer_menu_text_item}>Sort by price: high to low</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          
          </View>

        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Here is my parent component

```
export default class MainActivity extends Component

 {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: false,
      page: 1,
    };
    //this.sortby = this.sortby.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.setState({ isLoading: true }, this.getData)
  }


  sortby = (value) => {

    console.log(value);    
    console.log('............');
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    fetch(web_url + 'wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=' + web_consumerKey + '&consumer_secret=' + web_consumerSecret + '&per_page=26&page=' + this.state.page + '&status=publish&orderby=' + value)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ data: this.state.data.concat(data), isLoading: false });
        console.log(data);
        console.log('value vala nhi');
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  }


  getData = () => {
    fetch(web_url + 'wp-json/wc/v3/products?consumer_key=' + web_consumerKey + '&consumer_secret=' + web_consumerSecret + '&per_page=26&page=' + this.state.page + '&status=publish')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ data: this.state.data.concat(data), isLoading: false });
        // console.log(data);
        // console.log('value vala nhi');
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  }

  renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    let { images, categories, meta_data, id } = item;

    if (!images[0]) return null;
    let details = images[0];

    if (!id) return null;
    let productid = item.id

    return (

      <View>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',
          }}
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('ViewProduct', { productid: item.id, product_name: item.name })}
        >

          <Image
            style={{ width: 170, height: 200, borderRadius: 10 }}
            source={{ uri: details.src }}
          />

          <View style={styles.gridItemImage}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 13, color: 'black', textAlign: 'center' }}>
              {item.name}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.gridItemText}>₹ {item.price} </Text>

          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>

    );
  }

  // keyExtractor = (item, index) => {
  //   return index.toString();
  // }

  handleLoadMore = () => {

    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 }, this.getData)

  }

  renderFooter = () => {
    return (
      <View>

        < TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={this.handleLoadMore} style={styles.loadMoreBtn} >
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>Click Load More </Text>
          {
            (this.state.isLoading)
              ?
              <ActivityIndicator color="white" size='samll' style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} />
              :
              null
          }
        </TouchableOpacity >

      </View>
    );
  }




  render() {
    const { data, isLoading } = this.state;

    return (

      <View style={{ height: '100%', }}>
      

        <View style={{ height: '10%', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
          <CategoryData navigation={this.props.navigation} />

        </View>

        <View style={{ height: '80%' }}>

          <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}>
            <SafeAreaView style={{ marginTop: 10 }}  >

              {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator size="large" color='#0d1a4a' style={{ marginTop: 50 }} /> : (

                <FlatGrid
                  data={data}
                  style={styles.gridView}
                 // keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                 keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

                  renderItem={this.renderItem}
                  //onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
                  onEndReachedThreshold={500}
                  ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
                />

              )}
            </SafeAreaView >
          </ScrollView>

        </View>


      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find your child component being rendered in the parent component.

But it noticed that your component `CustomDrawerContent` is a functional component, and you are using this.props inside it.

Since the component is functional, you can't use `this.`, because this is exclusive to class, since you already are receiving props as a function parameter at `CustomDrawerContent` you can simply change `this.props.sortby` to `props.sortby`

Comment: Glad!  For the help.
Could you please let me know how can I render the child component to my parent?
I'm newbee in react native
@otacílio-maia